# How to show only a portion of an image just by using the img tag?

Tags: css

Currently, all my images look like this:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<img class="photo" src="foo.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
.photo {
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   background: #fff;
   width: 64px;
   height: 64px;
   display: block;
}
```

This expects the aspect ratio of the image to always be 1:1. Now, a new project requirement has come in that the images do not have to be 1:1. Rather, they can be tall rectangles:

[image]

In this case, I would like to only reveal the topmost square of the image:

[image]

How can this be done with a single `<img>` tag? I know how to do it with two tags - just wrap the `img` with a `div`, apply 3px padding to the div and place the URL as the `background-image` of the `img`. But I would like to know how to do this in a cleaner way, without an additional HTML tag.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you had looked at my solution earlier or not, but because jsfiddle was not working last night, I could not refine it (and thus it wasn't doing what I expected) until today. So if you looked before and noted that it didn't work, try looking again. There is still one little piece of the puzzle to resolve to get it cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Final Update--tested IE8+**: [This solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7SA/51/) uses a refinement of Surreal Dreams' idea of using outline for getting the border. This allows a cross browser simplicity compared to [the linear-gradient method](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7SA/45/) I was previously going for. It works in IE7, except the `outline` (unsupported).

Keeping it as an `img` tag with a `src` keeps it semantic.

A `margin: 1px` is applied to give the `outline` "space" in the layout, since by nature `outline` takes up no space. The zero height suppresses the main image, and the padding is used create the desired height for the background image (which is set the same as the main image) to show.

HTML

```
<img class="photo" src="foo.png" style="background-image: url(foo.png)" />
```

CSS

```
.photo {
   padding: 64px 0 0 0;
   border: 3px solid #fff;
   outline: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 1px;
   width: 64px;
   height: 0px;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: I need to get it working in IE8 and 9 and gradients don't work in those browsers.

Comment: @JoJo--done! Using a refinement of Surreal Dreams' idea for bordering it, we have an img tag doing what you desire, working in IE8+.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the `clip` property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Here an example with your image:
http://jsfiddle.net/2U3CE/1/

Code:

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    clip:rect(0,73px,73px,0);
}
```

Comment: The only downside to this method is it **only works with when position is set to either absolute or fixed**, which makes for a horrible time in organizing your page.

Comment: I cannot have absolutely/fixed position images as @aminuson points out.

Comment: yes, this is nerving. you could put a div with `position:relative;` around the images, but that would not be very pretty.

Comment: NOTE: clip is now deprecated and [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do this with a single tag - one div.  Does it matter that it's not one img tag?

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: url(test.jpg);"></div>
```

You never use an `<img>` tag, you just set up the div and you're done.  Set the size, add padding, border, etc, and preferable put all the reusable styles into a class and set the background image on a per div basis.  You end up with this:

```
<div class="hip2bsquare" style="background: url(test.jpg);"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hip2bsquare {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This uses the border to add white and outline to add black.  It's probably an abuse of the box model, but it should give you the visual.

Comment: Using a division removes the semantic meaning of the image, though.

Comment: The poster seemed much more interested in doing this with a single tag, not preserving the semantic meaning of the code.

Comment: I'm just throwing that out there. Whether the OP likes the idea or not, anyone who might stumble across the page in the future should know that.

Comment: This solution does not let me add a black border and white padding.

Comment: I've added a CSS class that will give you the visual. It's a little bit of a hack, but it should work.

Comment: I'm having problems saving, so here's the CSS class: .hip2bsquare {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}

Comment: @animuson--I solved the semantic issue with my answer. I have to thank Surreal Dreams, however, for the idea on the bordering.

Answer (score 0):

Use clip

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the CLIP property within CSS:

```
.photo-clipped {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,64px,64px,0px);
}

<img src="some_image.gif" class="photo photo-clipped" />
```